# postfix message delivery status via web call

Tags: email, postfix, email-bounces

is there a way I can configure postfix (or any other mail solution) to call a url with the status of submission?
example message with id 123efd was bounced it will call

```
https://mailnotifiapi.com/index.php?id=123efd&status=bounce
```

thank you

Comment: I'm writing a small newsletter service, and I want to get the status of each message so I can provide the user detailed statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is enabling a web interface to access (statistics of) the logs.

There are approaches that don't involve any web calls from the mail server. After all, mail servers don't even handle current logging by themselves but send everything to a logging daemon.

1. You could write a script that investigates your `mail.log` and run it as a cronjob. While this approach doesn't give real-time information, creating a static page would be efficient.
2. Write your logs to a SQL server. The syslog-ng has [`sql()` driver](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-sql.html) and rsyslog has [omlibdbi](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omlibdbi.html) for this purpose. Then simply allow your web interface to access these tables and you can do the statistics in real-time.